# Trying to customize this facebook sharing link, but the content getting shared is random, anyway I can force this?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have a customized share button using this code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<url here>"><i class="social fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social-fb"></i></a>
```

and I'm specifying what I would like it to say and display here:

```
<!--facebook share directions-->
<meta property="fb:app_id"          content="1234567890" /> 
<meta property="og:type"            content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:url"             content="url here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"           content="title here" /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="image here" /> 
<!--facebook share directions-->
```

but when I go to share it pulls a random picture and random text to appear in the post, is there any way for me to force this? could it be stuck in cache? I'm completely stuck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sharing, you will could use the feed dialog, that's the only way to define what will be shared in your story. But if you really want to use Open Graph, you will have to implement it correctly and sometimes need to wait a few days. I would need to take a look at the website, or at least see your full head code, are you using any Canonical URL tag? If the implementation is all correct, you need to wait a couple days, and try sharing it again. If you still having the same share, you can now use Facebook url **scraper** , the Open Graph object debugger, its on the platform website. But, my friend, honestly, sharing with "" is not functional, have a very bad user experience, popup blocking, and lots of other issues. Please, implement Facebook JS SDK, even if you choose to keep using share instead of FEED .